# How to wait for API call in the background before moving to the next page in .NET test using Playwright?

Tags: c#, playwright

I am writing my test in .net, I used the below, basically you fill out the text field, that calls an API, but the API call is not quick, the return on the front end is quick, but the call is still being made in the background, so the test tries to move onto the continue button, when it clicks that it falls down as it won't reach the next page as the API hasn't returned the result.

```
await Page.GetByTestId("TEXT FIELD").FillAsync("ABC123"); 
await Page.GetByTestId("Button").ClickAsync();await                    
await.Page.GetByTestId("Result").IsVisibleAsync();
await Page.WaitForLoadStateAsync();
await Page.GetByTestId("Continue_Button").ClickAsync();
await Page.WaitForURLAsync("**/URL", new PageWaitForURLOptions() { WaitUntil =   WaitUntilState.Load});
```

So to hack around this I added a loop that looks like this

```
Boolean visible = false;
while (visible == false)
{
    visible = await Page.GetByTestId("Result").IsVisibleAsync();
}
```

My test will work, but this seems to be not an ideal solution. Does anyone know of anything that can make this wait for the result before moving on?

Answer (score 1):

You can [wait for response](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response):

```
// Waits for the next response with the specified url.
await page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () =>
{
    await page.GetByText("trigger response").ClickAsync();
}, "http://example.com/resource");

// Alternative way with a predicate.
await page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () =>
{
    await page.GetByText("trigger response").ClickAsync();
}, response => response.Url == "https://example.com" && response.Status == 200);
```